# Child component does not load event of parent component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

I creating chat application by `React`.
In the chat application, there is a field for entering `user_name` and `text`.
I thought about managing those data with `state`, I made `onNameChange` and `onTextChange` events.
However, in the code I created, `onTextChange` was loaded but `onNameChange` was not loaded.

I know that `onTextChange` in the same file will be loaded.
Even though the files are different, I thought that data can be exchanged via props if the relationship is between parent and child.
I described the code with such a recognition, but I could not get the results I expected.

**How can I pass data from `LogoutStateForm.js` to `user_name` in `ChatForm.js` via `onNameChange`?**

`ChatForm.js`

```js
import React,{Component} from 'react'
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import { firebaseApp,firebaseDB } from '../firebase/firebase'
import LogoutStateForm from './LogoutStateForm'

const messagesRef = firebaseDB.ref('messages')

class ChatForm extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.onNameChange = this.onNameChange.bind(this)
    this.onTextChange = this.onTextChange.bind(this)
    this.state = {
      user: null,
      user_name: "",
      text: ""
    }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      this.setState({ user })
    })
  }
  onNameChange(e) {
    if (e.target.name == 'user_name') {
      this.setState({
        user_name: e.target.value
      }),
      console.log(this.state.user_name);
    }
  }
  onTextChange(e) {
    if (e.target.name == 'text') {
      this.setState({
        text: e.target.value
      }),
      console.log(this.state.text);
    }
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div id='Form'>
        {this.state.user ?
          <LogoutStateForm onClick={this.onNameChange} />:
          null
        }
        //In order to switch display depending on login availability
        <textarea name='text' onChange={this.onTextChange}  placeholder='メッセージ'/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ChatForm
```

`LogoutStateForm.js`

```js
import React,{Component} from 'react'
import firebase from 'firebase/app'

class LogoutStateForm extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }
  login() {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      this.setState({ user })
    })
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div className='logout'>
        <input name='user_name' onChange={this.props.onNameChange} placeholder='名前'/>
        <button onClick={this.login}>Goggle Login</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default LogoutStateForm
```

Please lend me your wisdom.
Thank you.

Comment: I haven't seen you use `LogoutStateForm` component in `ChatForm` component. Just `LoginStateForm`.

Comment: @TamDc Thank you for teaching for me. I edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in ChatForm.js, what you render LoginStateForm not LogoutStateForm.

Second, assuming it's supposed to be LogoutStateForm, at ChatForm component you pass onNameChange as onClick to LogoutStateForm. 
However, you access the props as onNameChange in LogoutStateForm which is wrong. You should access it as the props name that you give, which is this.props.onClick.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for teaching to `this.props.onClick` way. My problem was solved for your way. Thank you for your cooperation.

Answer (score 0):

In ChatForm.js, you are rendering wrong component, It should be LogoutStateForm.

Second you should access prop which you have passed.

ChatForm.js

```
<LogoutStateForm onNameChange={this.onNameChange} />
```

In LogoutStateForm.js

```
render(){
    return(
      <div className='logout'>
        <input name='user_name' onChange={this.props.onNameChange} placeholder='名前'/>
        <button onClick={this.login}>Goggle Login</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Also, define PropTypes in LogoutStateForm.js for verifying type check.

https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html